# Передача токена при работе с API Яндекс.Диска (Java)

Tags: java, yandex-disk

Я отсылаю запрос

> https://cloud-api.yandex.net:443/v1/disk/resources/download?path=%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B3.txt

но сюда нужно еще прикрутить заголовок в котором передается токен.

> Полученный токен следует передавать в заголовке Authorization при
> каждом вызове API Диска, указывая тип токена перед его значением.
>
> Пример такого заголовка: Authorization: OAuth
> 0c4181a7c2cf4521964a72ff57a34a07

[Код на pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/UCWVE10e):

```
public String stringUrlRequesDowload( String fileName ) {
    String response = "";
    String urlRequest = "https://cloud-api.yandex.net:443/"
                        +versionAPI+"/disk/resources/"
                        +"download?path="+fileName;
    try {
        URL urlString = new URL(urlRequest);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlString.openStream()));
        response = bufferedReader.readLine();
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println(response);
    return response;
}
```

Подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: А как вы посылаете запрос? Пример кода был очень кстати.

Comment: Не судите строго как - то так
  http://pastebin.com/UCWVE10e

Comment: Код надо добавить в вопрос, а не в комментарий.

Comment: Добавил так нормально ?

Answer (score 7):

Если вы используете URLConnection, то надо использовать метод `setRequestProperty`. В вашем случае будет что-то типа:

```
сonnection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "OAuth " + authToken);
```

Более подробно можно посмотреть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15555952/1646082). Где взять authToken должно быть описано в документации Yandex'a.

Comment: Спасибо сейчас попробую)

Comment: Все получилось спасибо))))

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, не забудьте отменить его как правильный. Галочка под оценкой.