# Добавление заголовка в запрос Java

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

Здравствуйте, господа! Работал тут с API ЯДиска, все шло хорошо до момента отправки авторизации не из SDK. Тут просят сделать так:

> Полученный токен следует передавать в заголовке Authorization при
>   каждом вызове API Диска, указывая тип токена перед его значением.
>   Пример такого заголовка: Authorization: OAuth 0c4181a7c2cf4521964a72ff57a34a07

Оно бы и хорошо, но:

```
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization: OAuth", "0c4181a7c2cf4521964a72ff57a34a07");
```

Отдают ошибку:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character(s) in message header field: Authorization: OAuth
```

Я понимаю, что есть ошибка, но с утреца чего-то не могу придумать, как её решить, ибо заголовки никогда не передавал почти. Кто может, подскажите решение, пожалуйста.
Заранее спасибо!

**Исправленный код:**

```
connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth 0c4181a7c2cf4521964a72ff57a34a07");
```

Comment: Русские буквы в заголовке не очень, попробуйте сделать encode или что-то такое.

Comment: Да это я для примера, чтобы токен не светить :) Сейчас поменяю на нормальный...

Comment: Пробел тоже плохой символ... %20 или что-то такое должно быть

Comment: Хех. Сделал вот так:

Comment: URLEncoder.encode("Authorization: OAuth", "UTF-8") Написал теперь, что "Метод не разрешен"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно, ответ сформировался исходя из этих двух вопросов:

- [Передача токена при работе с API Яндекс.Диска (Java)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458238/java-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-yandex-api?rq=1)
- [API Яндекс диска](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/471581/api-%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0?rq=1)

В моем коде ошибка в:

> setRequestMethod("POST");

Здесь не надо делать POST, можно даже не указывать точный вид запроса

и в:

> "Authorization: OAuth", "0c4181a7c2cf4521964a72ff57a34a07"

Здесь такая форма записи дает две ошибки:

- ":" не воспринимается
- OAuth должен находиться в ключе

Все ошибки выше поправлены, надеюсь кому-нибудь позже помогут :)

Answer (score 0):

Как пример. Знаю, что прошло 4 года, но это немного лучше предыдущих ответов.

```
uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth A9HRU2q0kfjhY5frhDDb4");
```

где uc - URLConnection объект.